# Why does my keyboard partially turn off?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg

Description of problem: Every so often (every few days), my laptop keyboard partially turns off. When I say "partially", I mean that all text input is disabled, but some of my hotkeys still work. For instance, even when the keyboard is seemingly not working, I can still open a terminal with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A bit of backstory: I've had this problem for a long time, and on gnome I found a hack that if I click the application menu icon (bottom left of screen) and open and close that menu the keyboard turns back on. I've recently switched from GNOME to dwm, so I don't have any button like that, and to get my keyboard back I just end up rebooting by holding the power button.

What is happening here? The keyboard is still on to some degree, but text input doesn't work. And what does the gnome application menu do behind the scenes that somehow resets things?

I'd be happy to post logs if I knew which file. My hunch is `dmesg` or `xorg.log`.

My laptop is a Thinkpad 13 (2015?), running Ubuntu 20.04.1 with dwm 6.2.

Edit: So I found some possible weirdness in `xorg.0.log.old`. It seems like it is trying to apply my keyboard settings to all input devices. (Those 4 `Option` lines that keep reappearing are settings that I've set in that past. It seems like `xorg` thinks all my input devices are keyboards. Could this be it?

```
[     7.790] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[     7.790] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.791] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[     7.791] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[     7.796] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.796]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.29.0
[     7.796]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     7.796]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[     7.796] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[     7.796] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     7.796] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[     7.797] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.802] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.802] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.802] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[     7.813] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[     7.813] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     7.813] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.813] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,il"
[     7.813] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[     7.814] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp_led:scroll"
[     7.853] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.853] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.856] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[     7.856] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.856] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[     7.856] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     7.856] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[     7.856] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.857] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.857] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[     7.857] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device removed
[     7.877] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input8/event6"
[     7.877] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     7.877] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.877] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,il"
[     7.877] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[     7.877] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp_led:scroll"
[     7.878] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.878] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Edited. Note that this bug has been going on for years, well before 20.04

Comment: Has this always happened with the same hardware?

Comment: Yes. I've had this laptop for years, and this has been happening as long as I can remember.  I had the gnome hack so until now I wasn't so concerned about it.

Comment: Is there any evidence to support the theory this is a software issue as opposed to a hardware issue?  Does the problem persist when you boot a live session (Try Ubuntu)?

Comment: From the fact that **some** hotkeys still work leads me to believe that it is software. I would like to try to troubleshoot in a live session, but this bug is hard to recreate. I have no idea what's causing it and it's relatively rare.

Comment: @Nmath It's possible that I'm wrong and it is hardware. You would just have to explain how some of the keys still work.

Comment: Is it the same keys that go dead every time?  Because that sounds more to me like symptoms of a hardware issue like a bad trace or some other issue with the PCB.

Comment: All keys are dead, besides for very specific commands. 
Additionally, while the bug is happening, plugging in an external keyboard doesn't help. I can use my hotkeys from the external keyboard, but no text input.

Answer (score 1):

New registrant here, could not comment on the clarification thread due to lack of reputation.

I'm getting the same issue, booting from an Ubuntu 20.04.1 live USB drive.

Up to now I used 16.04, and never seen this issue before.

I have used this live USB device a few times in the last few days without the bug occuring.

With the bucky ("Windows") key I can open the dash, I type "gedit" (the characters appear in the search field), then Enter, then Gedit opens with a cursor on the first line, and I cannot type anymore. Alt+F4 however closes the window. (Ctrl+Alt+t for the terminal acts in a similar way.)

Impacts both the laptop's (Dell Precision 3510) built-in keyboard and the external USB keyboard.

I "solved" it with adding an additional keyboard layout (UK English) in settings:

Settings > Region & Language > Input sources section

This action triggered a log-out; after re-login (on the lock screen I did not need to type, on the live USB there is no password), typing works.

I have run the "Diagnostics" function in the BIOS menu, and all hardware passed green.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution!  May I suggest that you add more details about: "*I "solved" it with adding an additional input source (UK English)*" - This is really the only part of your answer that actually explains your solution, but it's not very clear.  Consider posting step-by-step instructions so a future visitor can easily apply your solution!  https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: I am very interested in hearing more. I've actually wiped my drive and reinstalled a different distro and the problem followed me(!), which makes me believe it is hardware in the end.
Could you please explain more about what you did to "fix" it?

Comment: I have written down everything I did, step by step. On the other hand however, now I feel the most important aspect of how I got rid of this might have been the part about logging out and back in. Since then I did not encounter this; it occurred only with the live installer USB.