# no keyboard working in anything

Tags: grub2, keyboard

Disaster doing a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. All went well, entered OS, D/L Google set my dual screens up etc.  then suddenly the keyboard stopped working. Tried 3 keyboards including screen keyboard. None worked. Apparently this is common in 20.04. tried shutting down but no type accepted for password so cant enter OS. Decided to try re-installing but keyboard does not work on that either. Cant enter name, language etc. so I shut down again. tried to reinstall ubuntu 18.04.

Screen says Error file  boot grub i386 pc normal mode not found entering rescue mode  Grub Rescue but wont accept typing so cant fix grub. Prior to this I tried to enter recovery mode but without keyboard I could not scroll down to recovery or any editing . also cannot bring up CLI  Also tried an old boot repair disk but again cant click on anything as the keyboard does not work, not even press enter to set language. In other words it looks like Ubuntu 20.04 has completely destroyed my computer.   I dual boot windows 10 on desktop PC.  No keyboard I cant scroll down in the boot menu to click windows, recovery mode or edit.
Just opened windows from the Bios. Cant get into windows although it opened normally as no keyboard will let me type in the password.  Is there any way I can wipe the SSD drive. Thankfully I backed everything up beore installing

Comment: Apparently this is common in 20.04. Where did you read this or who told you this? I do not think this is accurate.

Comment: Actually, this reminded me of my very first answer on this website (happens to be 20.04): https://askubuntu.com/a/1299861/1157519 Since then (half a year passed) I have not once experienced any similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

See thread:
[Ubuntu 20.04 - keyboard not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274890/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-not-working) for working solution.

This just happened with me doing a fresh reinstall of XUbuntu 20.04. No keyboard.  Did install using US keyboard (default)  & all seemed to go normally.  Keyboard is a expensive wired USB Logitech illuminated keyboard k740.

Thus cannot select OS at boot as no keyboard. After boots into Ubuntu have some keyboard capability but not enough to login to Stack Exchange.  Have to use cell phone for all web postings.

I was able recall that option #4 was my Windows-10 boot.  Thus after bootup I did get some simple keyboard commands and was able to edit Grub & make Windows-10 the default boot.  I previously had XUbuntu 20.04 on this computer since Jan, 2021. That installation had no keyboard problems. Once Windows loaded I had a keyboard but didn't have that at the boot selection menu.

==================================================

I changed the desktop motherboard from an older Intel to a Gigabyte motherboard and the problem persisted. My system was duel boot: Windows-10/ XUbuntu 20.04. I could only boot the default Windows without the keyboard working. The new motherboard had a plug for a PS-2 keyboard, however. I plugged that in and unplugged my Logitech USB keyboard. Then the keyboard worked & I was able to boot into XUbuntu 20.04. I added the file ( blacklist-intel_vbtn.conf : see linked thread) and now have keyboard working even with only the USB Logitech keyboard plugged in.